# Poisson and conditional distribution

Tags: probability, self-learning

> Given a source that emits photons let be $X$ the number of photons emitted in $s$ seconds. Let be $p$ the probability that photons reach a detector and let be $Y$ the number of photos that reached the detector after  $s$ seconds.
>
> I need to find:

1. Distribution of $X$;
2. $\mathbb{P}(Y=y \mid X=x)$;
3. Marginal distribution of $Y$.

**Q1**

$X\sim\mathrm{Po}(\lambda  s)$
$$\mathbb{P}(X=x)=e^{\lambda s}\dfrac{(\lambda s)^x}{x!}$$

**Q2**

Not sure about this:

$$\mathbb{P}(Y =y\mid X=x)=\binom{x}{y}p^y(1-p)^{x-y}$$

**Q3**

Any suggest?

Comment: The answer to Q2 is correct. The conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is binomial. As to the distribution of $Y$, it is Poisson with parameter $p\lambda s$. This may have been proved in your book already. It can be obtained from Q2 by using the Law of Total Probability and some manipulation.  You can find MSE discussions by searching under thinning Poisson

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I added a key word (thinning). The result has been proved a number of times on MSE.